# g77 compiler cannot find -lgcc_s

Tags: ubuntu, fortran, shared-libraries, gfortran, g77

I am trying to compile a model which is written in FORTRAN 77. I am not able to make the link for g77.

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS.

I am getting the below error

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s 
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [exe] Error 1
```

Now I don't know exactly how to link. Kindly help me to fix the problem.

Comment: not quite sure what "making the link for g77" means: what do you want to link against?

Comment: *How* do you build (compile and link)? Please [edit] your question to show the commands (copy-pasted as text, in full and complete) you use.

Comment: How do you compile the program?  What does `find /usr/lib -name 'libgcc_s.*'` print? I'm pretty sure Ubuntu without that lib would be feeling ill.

Comment: Also, how did you install the Fortran compiler? What other parts of GCC have you installed?

Comment: The exact question on the neighbour's site https://askubuntu.com/questions/346377/cannot-find-lgcc-s

Comment: Note g77 was superseded by gfortran in April 2005, is now deprecated, and has not been developed in a long, long time. I would very strongly recommend you use the newer gfortran.

Comment: To add to @IanBush comments, just run "sudo apt install gfortran" to install a reasonably current Fortran compiler, then compile with the command gfortran. Forget g77.